# Compatibility of SSD for macbook pro

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

Which SSD of 1TB-2TB is compatible and how much for Macbook Pro mid 2014 retina? I know there is OWC Auro pro X2, which is most compatible, but I would like to know how to determine compatibility woth some other brand. Any experience?

Comment: Hardware shopping is off topic. If you can make this one question about how to measure something objective or just about how to tell what’s compatible, that might be well on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had a better resource that made a matrix of repair parts, but it turns out to be very hard to keep up. In the end, I really depend on OWC in the US for this knowledge.

- https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/ssd/owc/macbook-pro

Since you already know about them, the value they provide is it’s not just about the physical form factor but drivers and testing. Anyone can sell you untested parts that meet spec, but providing service to make it easy to pick the correct part and support you with after sales returns is valuable to me. Worse, when you buy from someone that doesn’t even know if the parts have the correct drivers or don’t meet spec, it can waste a lot more than just your time.